# JSON.NET JProperty path inconsistency

Tags: json.net

I am trying to serialize a dictionary and to use JProperty Path property for each element. To simplify the case, my dictionary has 2 elements the key of the first one is "key1" and the key of the second one is "key1.extended". The json looks like this

`"Dictionary": {
      "key1": {
        "Text": "1",
        "Id": 0
      },
      "key1.extended": {
        "Text": "2",
        "Id": 1
      }
  }`

When looping through the JProperties the paths for Text properties are as follows:

Dictionary.key1.Text

Dictionary['key1.extended'].Text

Apparently, this works just fine when the object is deserialized, but when I want to check a specific element I am having troubles to recognize key1 as an element.

Any idea how to retrieve the path to all properties in the format

Dictionary['key1.extended'].Text

EDIT:
Here is the code to reproduce the issue

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {


        private class SomeText {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        private class parent {
            public Dictionary<string, SomeText> data { get; set; }
            public parent() {
                data = new Dictionary<string, SomeText>();
                data.Add("key1", new SomeText() { Text = "value 1" });
                data.Add("key1.extended", new SomeText() { Text = "value 2" });
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            parent p = new parent();

            string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
                                            new JsonSerializerSettings {
                                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                                            });


            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(strJson);
            foreach (JProperty property in FindTokensByName(jo, "Text")) {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{property.Path}:{property.Value}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static List<JToken> FindTokensByName(JToken containerToken, string name, bool findFIrstIndent = false) {
            List<JToken> matches = new List<JToken>();
            FindTokensByName(containerToken, name, matches);
            return matches;
        }

        private static void FindTokensByName(JToken containerToken, string name, List<JToken> matches, bool findFirstIndent = false) {
            if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Object) {
                foreach (JProperty child in containerToken.Children<JProperty>()) {
                    bool found = false;
                    if (child.Name == name) {
                        //matches.Add(child.Value);
                        matches.Add(child);
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if (!findFirstIndent || !found)
                        FindTokensByName(child.Value, name, matches);
                }
            }
            else if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Array) {
                foreach (JToken child in containerToken.Children()) {
                    FindTokensByName(child, name, matches);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line

```cs
            string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
                                            new JsonSerializerSettings {
                                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                                            });
```

returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "key1": { "Text": "value 1" },
    "key1.extended": { "Text": "value 2" }
  }
}
```

The console output for property path:value, after the loop is

```
data.key1.Text:value 1
data['key1.extended'].Text:value 2
```

the first path is
data.key1.Text

the second path is
data['key1.extended'].Text

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] -- i.e. code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I edited the question to add the example

Comment: You've shown that the `Path` value is rendered differently depending on whether the the property name contains a `.` or not, but why does that pose a problem for you?  What do you mean by *"when I want to check a specific element I am having troubles to recognize `key1` as an element."*?

Comment: I am using the path to identify the item. When key1 is presented as data.key1, my parser is treating it as a property of the dictionary ( I am inheriting the dictionary and adding some additional properties). When it is presented as data['key1.extended'] it is clear that it is a dictionary entry. I expect to see all entries in the same format and data.key1 should be data['key1']. I wonder if data.key1 is somehow a default format and JSON.Net switches on the fly to the other one when an entry with . occurs. I need to find a way to present all entries as  data['key1']